# Interrupting a right floating marginal column with wider elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a site layout with a main content area, a marginal column on the right. Below the main content there may go more elements, usually with the same width as the main content. But now it should be possible to create wider elements in this area and the marginal column should reflow automatically.

To make it short, what I want to achieve is something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/t0JWyo?p=preview)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div.content-area {
  outline: 3px solid black;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#main {
  width: 200px;
  float: none;
  min-height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.marginal {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  clear: both;
}
div.content-module {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.content-module.wide {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>This is how it should look like</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 500px; height: 90%;">
    <div class="marginal content-area">Marginal module</div>
    <div class="marginal content-area">Marginal module</div>
    <div class="marginal content-area">Marginal module</div>

    <div id="main" class="content-area">
      Main Area
    </div>

    <div class="content-module content-area">Content</div>
    <div class="content-module content-area wide">Content wide</div>

    <!-- Following div will be above, where the other marginal divs are -->
    <div class="marginal content-area">Marginal module</div>

    <div class="content-module content-area">Another content</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

...with the HTML code shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7QNXHE?p=preview).

```
<body>
  <div style="width: 500px; height: 90%;">
    <div class="marginal content-area">Marginal module</div>
    <div class="marginal content-area">Marginal module</div>
    <div class="marginal content-area">Marginal module</div>
    <div class="marginal content-area">Marginal module (should appear under 'Content wide')</div>

    <div id="main" class="content-area">
      Main Area
    </div>

    <div class="content-module content-area">Content</div>
    <div class="content-module content-area wide">Content wide</div>
    <div class="content-module content-area">Another content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My first attempt was removing the clear:both; style from the marginal modules. But this causes the marginal elements to align next to each other, side by side. But they have to be under each other.

Any idea how to achieve something like this?

Comment: I know of **NO** CSS layout method that would allow that except *possibly* CSS Grids and I'm doubful even then. I'd be thinking of an alternative layout method or javascript.

Comment: On reflection CSS Regions *might* have worked but they have almost no support.